# Wrapping call to iterator in try/catch when using yield

Tags: c#, try-catch, yield-return

I need to do some heavy, somewhat fragile logic in a method that I'm implementing as an iterator (using `yield`):

```
public IEnumerable<Things> GetMoreThings() {
    while (goodStuffHappens()) {
        Things moreThingsIWant = TemptFateAgain();
        if (moreThingsIWant.Any())
            yield return moreThingsIWant;
    }
}
```

Out in the calling method, I need to wrap the call to `GetMoreThings` in `try`/`catch` and `yield return` the result:

```
try {
    foreach (Things thing in Helpful.GetMoreThings())
        yield return thing;
}

catch (Exception e) {
    //crash, burn
}
```

The initiated will immediately realize that this is impossible - [there is no such thing as a yield inside a `try`/`catch` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch) (only `try`/`finally`).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you actually want to just ignore the exception, or is there some code in the `catch` block that you're not showing?

Comment: Yes, there is significant code there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the answers here were correct. There's no built-in shortcut for this one, you need to tease apart the iterator in a `while` rather than a `for` loop in order to separate between the call to `Enumerator.MoveNext()` and the use of `Enumerator.Current`.

```
IEnumerator<Things> iterator = Helpful.GetMoreThings.GetEnumerator();
bool more = true;

while (more) {
    try {
        more = iterator.MoveNext();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //crash, burn
    }

    if (more)
        yield return iterator.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `Helpful.GetMoreThings()` call and enumeration separately from the `yield`:

```
try {
    var results = Helpful.GetMoreThings().ToList();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    //crash, burn
}

foreach (Things thing in results)
    yield return thing;
```

Something like that.

If you need this to be lazy the code gets really nasty. You can no longer use `foreach`. You need to write the iteration loop manually and the code size explodes to like 20 lines of illegible mess. I know because I did this yesterday.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be lazy. Otherwise I have trouble coming up with a good reason to design it this way.

Comment: Then, do what the last paragraph says: Expand the foreach into a manually written loop. You can then call MoveNext() with a catch guard and yield without catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `Catch()` extension method from Ix.Net](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Ix-Main/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx/M/Catch%28TSource,TException%29), or just copy [its Apache-licensed source code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx.Exceptions.cs#L10). The code could look like this:

```
return Helpful.GetMoreThings().Catch((Exception e) =>
{
    // crash, burn
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The source code is actually the 20 illegible mess lines referred to above in the answer from @usr.